# Align Imageview in a row [right of each other] in scrollview in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android development and I'm making an android app that requires Images to be aligned next to each other (3 images in each row along with text to the bottom of each image). I want to put in scroll view(and add more images) but whenever i do so, the images become disordered. Tried using linearlayout with scrollview, but the case is same. Heres an example of what i want it to look like(with the ability to scroll using scrollview):

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/efB3q.png -screenshot

Here's my XML code:

http://pastebin.com/VvC2y46c

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using GridLayout. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Or you can use GridView and scrap your ScrollView.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Your current method isn't very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You could almost copy the [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) documentation verbatim, and swapping in your desired width/height combination:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Then, in your own `ImageAdapter` class, add in your own drawable resources:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // more here
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] thumbIds = {
            R.drawable.youtube,
            R.drawable.twitter,
            R.drawable.sony,
            // more here
        };
```